# JPA managed mapping with different entities error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I have a form and this form need to update my record but apparently not updating and i get below error message. Dealing this exception with in 4 days and i decide to ask a question. If you need an extra information i can add some.

JSP Exception;

```
MergeContext#attempt to create managed -> managed mapping with different entities: [main.model.Users#1]; [main.model.Users#1]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: MergeContext#attempt to create managed -> managed mapping with different entities: [main.model.Users#1]; [main.model.Users#1]
```

Java Exception;

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: MergeContext#attempt to create managed -> managed mapping with different entities: [main.model.Users#1]; [main.model.Users#1]
```

Controller; its get Position User and Domain info from form and saves it to DB;

```
@PostMapping("/save-personel-info")
public String savePersonelInfo(@RequestParam int id, HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("Users") Users users, @ModelAttribute("Positions") Positions positions, @ModelAttribute("Domains") Domains domains, ModelMap model){
    usersService.save(users);
    request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_USERS");
    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

Service;

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UsersService {

    public void save(Users users){
        usersRepository.save(users);
    }
}
```

Form;

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/save-personel-info" modelAttribute="Users">
    <tr>
        <form:input id="1-1-0" type="hidden" class="form-control" path="id"/>
            <td><form:input id="1-1-0" type="text" class="form-control" path="username" /></td>
            <td><form:input id="1-1-0" type="text" class="form-control" path="mail" /></td>
        <td>
            <form:select path="Positions" class="form-control">
                <form:options items="${Pst}"  itemValue="id" itemLabel="position_name" />
            </form:select> 
        </td>                                   
        <td>
            <form:select path="Domains" class="form-control">
                <form:options items="${Domains}"  itemValue="id" itemLabel="domain_name" />
            </form:select> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
```

User Class;

```
@Component
@Entity
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;
    public String username;
    public String mail;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date enrolment_date;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Domains domains;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Positions positions;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = UserLanguages.class, mappedBy = "users", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<UserLanguages> userlanguages = new HashSet<UserLanguages>();

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = UserCertificates.class, mappedBy = "users", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<UserCertificates> usercertificates = new HashSet<UserCertificates>();

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = UserKnowledge.class, mappedBy = "users", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<UserKnowledge> userknowledge = new HashSet<UserKnowledge>();
```

What is the meaning of "managed mapping with different entities" i research the this error message but i guess no one get this error. [Hibernate-orm](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/MergeContext.java)

Comment: Same problem. Let me know if you have already resolved this issue, please.

Comment: @semenchikus Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error message says that Hibernate has detected invalid 'managed entity' -> 'managed entity' mappings where key != value.

`MergeContext` stores mappings of managed entities to merged entities (and vice versa) and I guess that somehow you have two distinct managed entities loaded at the same time that represent the same record in the database (that's why you can get this error). <sup>(Source: [internal source code of Hibernate Core](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.9.Final/org/hibernate/event/internal/MergeContext.java) analysis)</sup>

It's hard to say from the provided example where another one `Users` entity is. So I'm writing here a few ideas:

- `Users` entity may be defined in `Domains`, `Positions`, `UserLanguages`, `UserCertificates`, or `UserKnowledge` classes. If you find it there with `CascadeType.ALL` / `CascadeType.PERSIST`, remove `cascade` property.
- If somewhere you're using `Users` entities in a collection and trying to persist it, you may also encounter this error. Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of `Users` class and use a `Set` to ensure object uniqueness. The `equals()` method may be as simple as comparing ids:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) {
          return true;
      }
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
          return false;
      }

      Users that = (Users) o;

      return getId() == that.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return Long.valueOf(getId()).hashCode();
  }
  ```
- Look carefully for other `Users` entities in your program and do `session.evict(users)` to remove the object instance from the session cache.

Answer (score 0):

And sometimes it's just a bug in Hibernate:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12439?attachmentViewMode=gallery

> Description
>   Depending on the initialization order of entities a
>   cascaded merge is failing with an IllegalStateException like:
>
> ```
> 08:26:15,502 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-1) WFLYEJB0034: 
> EJB Invocation failed on component Bean for method public abstract void 
> org.jboss.playground.BeanRemote.errorTest(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String):
> javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:  
> MergeContext#attempt to create managed -> managed mapping with different entities:    
> [org.jboss.playground.Frd#9]; [org.jboss.playground.Frd#9]
> ```
>
> ...